# Throttle Cosmos DB throughput while querying

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a method that queries a Cosmos DB collection like this:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<TObject> Query(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> filter)
{
    FeedIterator<TObject> feedIterator = this.CosmosClient
        .GetContainer(this.DatabaseName, this.CollectionName).GetItemLinqQueryable<TObject>()
        .Where(filter)
        .ToFeedIterator();

    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<TObject> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (TObject r in response.Resource)
        {
            yield return r;
        }
    }
}
```

This utilizes the maximum throughput so that the database may become unresponsive. In cases where the query takes a long time to complete but has low priority, I would like to throttle the throughput it consumes by adding an extra parameter to the method:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<TObject> Query(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> filter, 
    double maxThroughputInRUsPerSecond)
```

I know I can retrieve the consumed throughput with `response.RequestCharge`. What would be a good way to estimate the RU/s, and how should I add back off delays to (approximately) limit the throughput to the given value?

Comment: There is no such throttle mechanism built-in. If you're trying to avoid throttling, you would need some mechanism of your own (or increase RU/sec during busy times, or create a separate collection specific for a set of queries, etc). As far as estimating RU consumed: you've already figured out that each operation returns its `RequestCharge` cost. You can do something with those values to help predict congested time periods (maybe log them, stream them, query them over time, etc) - again, no specific way - you'll need to come up with something that works best for you.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks, I know. I was just hoping someone had some code samples showing how to do this sensibly since it's not trivial.

Comment: There is a way to do this but is only available via the Java SDK today with its throughput control. The alternative is, if this is a cross-partition query, implement a materialized view using Change Feed to make the query more efficient and use that secondary container to serve this query.